# how can I access the data that I just encoded using "_serialize" in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, json, cakephp

I have this function in my `UsersController`. I created this JSON response by using the `_serialize` key:

```
    public function test() {
    $arrEmail = $this->User->find('first');
    $this->set('foo', $arrEmail);
    $this->set('_serialize', array('foo') );
    }
```

Now in the client side, in my phonegap application, I am trying to access this data. So I put the following:

```
     <script>
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                alert(1);
                $.ajax({
                url : "http://localhost/database/users/" + 'test.json',
                async : false,
                cache    : false,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                success : function(result) {
                alert('success');
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                          },
                error : function(xhr, status, err) {
                //con failed
                    alert(err+' '+xhr+' '+status);
                }
        });
                 });
    </script>
```

The alert gives me the following [image: Alert result].

Now I need to access to the username and the other attributes. I tried `result.attributename` but i always get `undefined` as a response.

**EDIT:**

```
`result.foo.User.id` solved the issue.
```

Comment: Did you literally try `result.[attributename]`? You can use `.` or `[]` syntax, not both

Comment: no I meant result.attributename. without the square braquets.

Comment: Can you give an actual example of what you are trying to query? `result.foo.User.id` should produce 115. If it doesn't, try `alert(typeof result)` to ensure you are not working with a string

Comment: 'result.foo.User.id' worked for me. Thank you :)